# Post to and visit a URL in Javascript

Tags: javascript, post

I'm trying to:

- Post a JSON object to a URL and visit it at the same time.
- Set the content-type and accept headers

I'm working with an old source base (asp classic / vb). Ideally, if I can do this in javascript it would be wonderful!

Constructing the js call with headers and data is simple with XHR:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "url";
xhr.open("POST", url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
var data = JSON.stringify({JSON DATA});
xhr.send(data);
```

However this is an async call and I can't seem to find a way of making it actually visit the URL in the browser.

The alternative is to create an form and append it to a HTML entity before using javascript to submit it. This time is post the data to and visits to the URL.. however, I don't have control over the headers.

So back to my questions. Can I post to and visit a URL in Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Given that visiting an URL in the browser is a GET request, and you want to POST at the same time, **NO** you cannot.

Why do you need to post and visit?

You could post your data and in the callback (once the post request is done) load the the page.

Comment: I'm integrating with a 3rd party checkout provider that requires a post with JSON data and content header set. I'm not sure how to achieve if I can post and navigate..

Comment: on your latter point regarding posting the data and then loading the page.. does the target page when loaded have access to posted data in the ajax request? or is that considered a different request?

Answer (score 0):

No.

The closest you could come would be to:

1. Use Ajax to make the request
2. Use DOM to modify the current page with data from the response
3. Use the History API to update the URL in the address bar

Changing the server side code to expect regular form encoded data and then submitting a regular form would probably be the simplest approach to solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are using XHR, and if you want to manage it from javascript... Add **onreadystatechange** property to your xhr (this function will be fired when your server response), and in this function redirect using *window.location.href*

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    // Here redirect, with params if you need to
    window.location.href = "https://stackoverflow.com?name1=value1&name2=value2"; 
  }
};
var url = "url";
xhr.open("POST", url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
var data = JSON.stringify({JSON DATA});
xhr.send(data);
```